# How to remove sidebar primary widget on Mobile on category page

Tags: php, css, sidebar, mobile

Hello i have been trying to figure out how i can hide the sidebar only on Categories page on Mobile

I tried this code:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .sidebar {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

But it removes the sidebar on all pages. I just need to hide it on the category pages

Comment: For category wp adds `category` class to body tag. Try this: `.category .sidebar { display: none; }` inside you media query

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your code with below one:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { .category .sidebar { display: none; } }
```

if you want to hide in particular one category then use like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) { .category.*category-slug* .sidebar { display: none; } }
```